# Background-clip and transformation on a pseudoelement makes it disappear in Chrome

Tags: css, background, transform, pseudo-element

I'm working on a menu with animated link text background. I want to make the link text "fill up" with a different color on mouse over. This is basically simple: the "filling" color is a gradient background, the link text has `background-clip: text;` set and it works.

The problem is that the link text has an `:after` that contains an icon, which should be animated (rotated in this case) using css transform. The `after` pseudo-element needs to "fill up" with color just as the link text does, as if it was another "word" in the link text.

Works well in Firefox, but in Chrome there's a problem: the pseudo-element disappears as soon as any transformation kicks in. No matter what transformation it is (translate, rotate or other), the `after` disappears. Seems to me that css transformation and background-clip somehow exclude each other as it works well without transformations on the `after`.

I played with position, backface-visibility, and some other properties but no succes.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="link">
    <span class="link-text">This is the text of the link</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.link {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 700 20px/1.5em sans-serif;
    background: #eee;
}

.link-text {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0a0, #0a0 50%, #333 50%, #333);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.link-text:after {
    content: ' .x';
    transition: all 0.5s;
    display: inline-block;
}

.link:hover .link-text {
    background-position: 0 50%;
}

.link:hover .link-text:after {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Here is a pen to play with:
https://codepen.io/MPDoctor/pen/gOLobbN

Works in Firefox, fails in Chrome.

I'm running out of ideas, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I notice that the pseudo element is visible if you specifically give it a color (e.g. color: black), and it rotates on the hover (Edge/Chrome).

Comment: Yes, but it has to have `color: transparent` for the "color fill" effect to be visible.

Comment: Hey, if the link becomes broken in the future, the question will not be useful. There's a feature for making simple code examples inside Stack Overflow, just like CodePen. Try to use these instead.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't explain the problem seen in Chrome/Edge but it's a sort of workaround which may be OK in practice, depending on various factors like the speed of the transition, as humans may not notice the hack.

The after content is visible if given a color when it is being rotated, we can give it the dark color during the hover until the last minute when we give it the lime type color. So we use CSS animation rather than a transition:

```html
<head>
<style>
.link {
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 700 20px/1.5em sans-serif;
    background: #eee;
}

.link-text {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0a0, #0a0 50%, #333 50%, #333);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.link-text:after {
    content: ' .x';
    display: inline-block;
  animation-name: none;
}

.link:hover .link-text {
    background-position: 0 50%;
}

.link:hover .link-text:after {
  animation: rotate 0.5s linear 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    color: #333;
    }
    99% {
    color: #333;
    }
    100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    color: #0a0;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="link">
    <span class="link-text">This is the text of the link</span>
</a>
</body>
```

Comment: you can keep the use of transition to have also the fadeout: https://jsfiddle.net/uoj4ycbL/

Comment: The animation is not a bad idea, at least as a workaround. :-)
Although it would be nice to have a real solution o the problem, as in the project I'm working on there are plenty animations for the user to choose from and a code-minimal solution would greatly appreciated :)